# Arcs and sectors question

Tags: circles, arc-length

I am a student and I need help answering this question on arcs and sectors.

Question:

The sector has an angle of 35°. The arc length is 20cm. Find the circumference and radius of the whole circle.

Thank you and help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the **ratio** between the **arc length of the circle** and the **arc length of the sector** is $360:35$.

Hence, it follows that the arc length of the circle (Let's denote this by $C$) is given by:
$$C=20\times \frac{360}{35}$$

(I'll let you simplify the fraction)

---

From this, you can algebraically find the radius $r$ by using the formula for the circumference of a circle:
$$C=2\pi r$$